# Access controller by JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view called InvoiceTo and a Controller called Order. Using JQuery, the default URL is: `url: ''`, and this is the result:

`locahost:port/domain/order/InvoiceTo`

If I change the URL: `url: /Order/GetInformation`, this is the result:

`locahost:port/domain/order/InvoiceTo/Order/GetInformation`

I've already tried lots of way to set my url, but is always wrong. This is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#InvoiceToDrop').change(function () {
            var $div = $('#modalPartial'); 
            var idcustomer = $(this).val(); 
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Order/GetInformation/' + idcustomer,
                type: 'GET',                
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (error) {
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

What I have to do to have this URL:

`locahost:port/domain/Order/GetInformation/1`

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Why would you have `/domain/` in your URL? I believe in jQuery (and other libraries too) `/Order/GetInformation` should mean `localhost:port/Order/GetInformation`

Comment: Did you try this `url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Order", action = "GetInformation" })/' + idcustomer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [UrlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) `Url.Action` method in the view:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("GetInformation", "Order", new { customerId })',
    ...
```

Or

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetInformation", "Order")/' + idcustomer
```

When the view loads `@Url.Action` is parsed and is replaced by the actual value.

Advantages of using this method are that it uses the routing table rather than statically typed urls.